# SQL:Assign result in a local variable and use it in when condition

Tags: sql

I have a query like below

```
SELECT name from Employee 
WHERE Emp_id =?

   AND joining_DATE >= 
   case when (select max(joining_date) from Employee where emp_id = ? 
    then (select max(joining_date) from Employee where emp_id = ? 
    else  'start date' end
```

Here if you see closely same query is executed twice in case when and then. I want to execute this only once, if possible. If not possible then at least if anything can be done to execute max(salary) only once.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please describe what output you want, cause your query is confusing!

Comment: your case statement won't make sense at all? you need to explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: My problem is,  i want to execute the query in case when only once instead of twice. if not possible that then at least max() query only once. I know I can do that with PL/SQL but i dont want to use PL/SQL. I hope that clarifies your question.

Comment: @Ritesh Try to show some sample input and your expected output. Your query at the moment is very confusing.

Comment: What database system are you using - you mention PL/SQL - I think that term is used in both Oracle and Postgres, possibly others - could you add a tag for your specific system please?

Comment: Also, before you try too hard with this, be aware that in SQL, you generally tell the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*. Your system may, already, behind the scenes, be able to satisfy this query whilst only performing a single actual scan on the table. You may hack this all around and find that you've not improved the performance of the query at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use "with" clause.

```
WITH maxemp AS
 (select max(joining_date) as maxdate from Employee where emp_id = ?)
 SELECT name from Employee 
WHERE  joining_DATE >= 
 case maxemp.maxdate 
then maxemp.maxdate 
else  start_date end
```

Comment: Thanks Franek, with clause worked but not the way as in your example. It worked considering maxemp as a view and fetching data from this in from and where clause of select query. I have edited your response for the way it worked for me.